# Get listitem value

Tags: c#, winforms, listitem

Edit/Update!!!

I wanted to update the question as the answer below only guided me in the right direction but did not completely solve the issue.

However i did manage to fix the problem by changing how items and hopefully this will help someone in the future

Add items to the class list like so

```
descriptionclb.Items.Add(new listItem { Name = ItemToAdd, Price = Convert.ToDouble(ItemPrice), Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(Quantity.Text) });
```

And iterate items like so

```
    foreach (Listitem item in descriptionclb.Items)
    {
        double TotalAmmount = item.Price);
        //Do stuff with Item
    }
```

I'm trying to get the value of a list item within a listbox, I keep getting an error "'System.InvalidCastException'  Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'list'."

Any help would be appreciated,and I have tried to do lots of research with no result (Maybe im not phrasing the question right on google). See my code below.

Class ListItem

```
    public class listItem 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public double Quantity { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
```

I insert the values here

```
        Globals.li.Name = ItemToAdd;
        Globals.li.Price = Convert.ToDouble(ItemPrice);
        Globals.li.Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(Quantity.Text);

        descriptionclb.Items.Add(Globals.li.ToString());
```

Globals is a globlal class and li is the `listitem li = new listItem`

I get the error here

```
        foreach (var item in descriptionclb.Items)
        {
            double TotalAmmount = Convert.ToDouble(((list)item).Price);
        }
```

Comment: Set the DataSource of the ListBox to your `List<listItem>`. The DisplayMember = `listItem.Name`. Set the `ValueMember`, is required. Now, each Item of the ListBox is a `listItem` object you can cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding strings here:

```
descriptionclb.Items.Add(Globals.li.ToString());
```

So you are saving string rather than listItem object that is why you get the error.

Should be:

```
descriptionclb.Items.Add(Globals.li);
```

Also this object `descriptionclb.Items` should be of type listItem

And the for loop should something like:

```
foreach (listItem item in descriptionclb.Items)
        {
            double TotalAmmount = item.Price;
        }
```

Comment: Nope, it should not be `descriptionclb.Items.Add(Globals.li);`. Maybe `descriptionclb.Items.AddRange(Globals.li.ToArray());` (`Globals.li` should be a List<listItem>, to handle multiple objects). The single object is also (most probably) a mistake (trying to add the same item multiple times, changing its internal values, will change all the items in the ListBox).

Comment: @Jimi Globals.li is an object of type listItem, it doesn't have ToArray method

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but if I do that for some reason the newest item I add overwrites all the previous inputs and im stuck with multiple duplicate listitems

Comment: There, see the comment the OP left here.

Comment: @Jimi I'm using it somewhere else in the program, the single object I added was just an example and for testing. I'll give  his suggestion a try.

Comment: @TheITGuy you should change this: Globals is a globlal class and li is the listitem li = new listItem **TO** Globals is a globlal class and li is a List of listitem, List<listitem> li = new List<listItem>().

Comment: @The IT Guy If you want to keep an object reference somewhere (the last item added, maybe?), don't use it as the source of data of a multiple-object container, as the List of Items of ListBox. It's a single object, when you change the values in the object's reference, all values will change wherever this object is used. Use a `List<listItem>` to hold these values and use this List as the DataSource of the ListBox, as described in the comment I left in the question's section.

Comment: @ljcordero it seems like your answer is the way to go, bur for some reason i'm unable to get the item.price(Object doesn't contain a definition....), hens the reason why i wrote "double TotalAmmount = Convert.ToDouble(((list)item).Price);" any idea why?

Comment: @TheITGuy did you wrote the for loop as this:
`foreach (listItem item in descriptionclb.Items)
        {
            double TotalAmmount = item.Price;
        }`
?

Comment: @ljcordero I didn't, but i can't since i made it a gloal list, but i figured it out, I forgot to refrence the global list                                                                     'foreach (var item in descriptionclb.Items)
            {
                double TotalAmmount = Convert.ToDouble(Globals.list.Price);
            }'

Comment: @TheITGuy this way: 'foreach (var item in descriptionclb.Items) { double TotalAmmount = Convert.ToDouble(Globals.list.Price); }'
You are not using the item variable that iterate the values of the list.

Comment: Yeah, I realized ;) , but nothing works i'm still getting the same error. I did except the answer as changing to an array of lists is def the way to go

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have a type called 'list'. Your foreach loop iterates over a list of strings, therefore 'var item' is a string. You can't convert the 'list' type to a string which is causing the exception.

If you're trying to add all the 'listItem' Price values up then you should try changing the type of 'descriptionclb.Items' from a list of strings to a list of 'listItem' and add the listItem directly. Then you will be able to get rid of the cast.

```
descriptionclb.Items.Add(Globals.li);
```

```
foreach (var item in descriptionclb.Items)
{
    double TotalAmmount = item.Price;
}
```

Just a note; in the for loop you don't do anything with TotalAmmount.

Comment: descriptionclb is a listbox

Answer (score 0):

you need to change

```
 descriptionclb.Items.Add(Globals.li);
```

and

```
 foreach (var item in descriptionclb.Items)
{
    double TotalAmmount = item.Price;
}
```

if TotalAmmount , total fares from list cahnge it to:

```
 double TotalAmmount=0
        foreach (var item in descriptionclb.Items)
        {
             TotalAmmount = TotalAmmount+ item.Price;
        }
```

Comment: but if TotalAmmount total from amount can create double totalAmmount=0; and replace totalAmmount=totalAmmount+item.price;